# success call back or REST call not firing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

Successfully adding items to a list but **success** handler not firing.  Anybody know why?

```
function addListItem() {

    var guidance1 = $("#guidance1").val();
    var guidance2 = $("#guidance2").val();
    var guidance3 = $("#guidance3").val();
    var guidance4 = $("#guidance4").val();
    var guidance5 = $("#guidance5").val();

var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Travel Request')/items";

$.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Travel_x0020_Request_x0020_MemosListItem' },
        'Guidance1': guidance1,
        'Guidance2': guidance2,
        'Guidance3': guidance3
        }),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("Epic fail");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Is "error" being fired? Have you looked at the results using the browser's F12 tools?

Comment: no error shows in the developer tool

Comment: What's the returned status code shown in the F12 tools? Or is it returning at all?

Comment: data is being inserted into the list but no status code is being showed.

Comment: Only thing I see missing is content-length, but I don't think that is required. "type" vs. "method" was as issue at one time, but both should work today, especially as your data is being added. (but try changing "type" to "method" just in case.)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Is this in an App or a Content Editor web part, or something else?

Comment: I'm using jquery version 3.3.1  Changing "type" to "method" worked.   Thanks!